# How to configure Switch Router and Two Different Computer with one single Internet Connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I think this is quite a bit confusing for me. I have an **internet connection** that can only be accessed from **Computer-A**.
[image]

But then,... I have one **Switch WIFI Router TD-W8915ND**, and another computer, called as **Computer-B**.

Now the **computer-B is connected to the router via WIFI**. And also **the Computer-A also connected to the router via WIFI**. Then.... The question is, **how can I share my internet access, so anyone who connected to the router WIFI, can access the internet?**

*Rule 1: Do not plug-off the Internet LAN cable of Computer A. LAN Cable can only be used by Computer-A.*

Comment: Your question is unclear: the short answer is generally that you do not have to do anything because commonly available routers these days perform Network Address Translation to allow any number of computers connected to them to all share internet access with a single IP address leased from your ISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure the following:

1. You need to run NAT (Network address Translation) on Computer A on the WIFI interface -
   presumably you would use "connection sharing" in Windows.
2. You would treat your WIFI router as an Access Point + Switch - you want to disable
   DHCP on it as Computer A would be doing the connection sharing.  You would also want
   to ensure nothing is connected to the WAN port of the WIFI router, and that its LAN
   port is statically assigned in the address range associated with the WIFI interface
   on Computer A, but outside the DHCP range.
3. Set up computer B (and other devices like it) as you regularly would if connecting
   to a Wireless Access Point.

Comment: yes, you're right! Hehe.... that's quite clear for me!